# How to pull the "Requirement Status" field from JIRA in Confluence?

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-plugin

I am trying to generate dynamic reports in Confluence by pulling data from User Stories in JIRA. We use Xray Plugin in JIRA hence it has the requirement status field to show the passed/failed cases.

This field generally shows [NORUN], [NOK] etc. unless you hover over the field, hence when I pull this field from JIRA to Confluence all I see if [NOK] rather than the passed/failed cases.

Can someone help me troubleshoot this?